# SilverStripe get by id in exact order

Tags: php, sql, silverstripe

Suppose you have an array of keys

```
$key_list = array(3, 6, 2);
```

And you want to retrieve records from a certain table, using these keys as identifiers (WHERE ID = id_from_key_list)

```
Foo::get()->byIDs($key_list);
```

This returns the rows with the ID's that match those in `$key_list` (3, 6 and 2) **but not in that order**.

How do we maintain the same order when retrieving these items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might need to do is to run a foreah loop of the IDs and push each Foo Object into an ArrayList

```
$aFooList = ArrayList::create(); 
foreach ($key_list as $key_list_id){
   $oFoo = Foo::get()->byID($key_list_id);
   $aFooList->push($oFoo); 
}
return $aFooList;
```